# Why does the UpdateMethod in ObjectDataSource only receive values for properties from visible controls in DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, detailsview

I've written a class that contains Select- and Update-Methods for an ObjectDataSource. The UpdateMethod receives an instance of a called class. My problem is, that only properties that are Bound in the DetailsView are set, the others have their default value.

Here's my code:

**Class declaration**:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Prop1 {get;set:}
  public int Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

**Updatemethod**:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
public static void UpdateQuicklink(Foo item)
{
//  item.Prop1 // contains correct value
// item.Prop2 // is 0
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="ods" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prop1"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prop2" Visible="false"/>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server"
    TypeName="NamespaceToClassContaingUpdateMethod"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    DataObjectTypeName="NamespaceToFoo" 
    UpdateMethod="UpdateQuicklink">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I can't expose every field I need to the markup.
A possible solution would be to rewrite my UpdateMethod to accept all necessary parameters, like that:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
public static void UpdateQuicklink(string Prop1, int Prop2)
{

}
```

But this solution is crap, due to I it is not flexible enough, if I attempt changes to the underlying datastructure. I know that in that case I'd have to edit my code nevertheless, but I'd to only have my custom wrapper class as parameter. Is that possible?

Comment: Just to make sure if I understand the question correctly: You say "that only properties that are Bound in the DetailsView are set, the others have their default value" but in your markup example `Prop2` IS actually bound, it's just not visible. Does your problem occur now with properties which are really not bound (not existing in markup at all) or which are bound but not visible?

Comment: Only values that are bound to a visible control are properly set. Switching to Visible="true" would cause to set prop2 properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the values of invisible `DataControlFields` (like `BoundField`) are not included in the ViewState and therefore not preserved during a roundtrip. [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1012473.aspx) is a discussion about the issue. Microsofts recommendation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.visible.aspx) is to add the field name for invisible fields to the `DataKeyNames` property of the data-bound control. You can remove then the invisible field from the `Fields` collection:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="ods" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
    AutoGenerateRows="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    DataKeyNames="Prop2">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Prop1"/>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

That's not necessary for Controls in a Template - like a TextBox in an EditItemTemplate of a FormView which is bound using `Text='<%# Bind("Prop2") %>'`. Here ViewState is preserved during roundtrips even for an invisible TextBox (unless you disable ViewState of course).

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of awswer I was looking for ;)

Comment: Haha, and it was even a luck for myself that I had looked for a solution to your question. Because today I had a very similar issue with an EntityDataSource and a field in a FormView which wasn't declaratively bound (only assigned in code-behind). Similar problem with updating the value. Then I remembered... "wasn't there this question?" ...and I've tried this "DataKeyNames" trick with that field and voila... it works! (I feel this really to be a weird "trick" or misuse of the property - recommended by MS or not - because my field has nothing to do with a "key".)